# Profile Java process on AIX with VisualVM

Tags: java, profiling, aix, visualvm, remote-process

I have connected VisualVM via JMX to an AIX server to profile my Java process. But the "Profiler" tab is missing I just get Overview, Monitor and Threads.

Have I missed any configuration? When opening a local Java process I see the "Profiler" tab. Or isn't it possible to profile a remote application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of VisualVM do you use? "Profiler" tab is not available for remote applications, but you should be able to use ["Sampler" tab](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/visualvm-12-great-java), which uses JMX connection to do CPU sampling of your remote application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible.

From the JVisualVm documentation:

> **Note.** Java VisualVM can retrieve monitoring information on remote applications but it cannot profile remote applications.

You might want to refer to this for remote profiling: [Is there a remote profiler for Java? (that uses JMX preferably)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468135/is-there-a-remote-profiler-for-java-that-uses-jmx-preferably)